# pyzmq / ZeroMQ: Why could manual reading of a multipart message lead to problems in combination with AsyncIO?

Tags: python-3.x, zeromq, python-asyncio, pyzmq

I am reading data from a ZeroMQ socket using pyzmq. The code also uses
`websockets` so chose to use `asyncio` for ZeroMQ on the subscriber side, too.

The subscriber has to read a multipart message. Instead of using `socket.recv_multipart()`
I chose to make use of `pyzmq`'s convenience functions for receiving and sending

```
import zmq
import zmq.asyncio         
        
context = zmq.asyncio.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)

address = await socket.recv_string()
print(socket.RCVMORE)
clock = await socket.recv_pyobj()
print(socket.RCVMORE)
data = await socket.recv_pyobj()
```

The publisher also uses the convenience functions, does not use asyncio:

```
socket.send_string('raw', zmq.SNDMORE)
socket.send_pyobj(time.time(), zmq.SNDMORE)
socket.send_pyobj(d.data)
```

Usually the code works fine. But sometimes it failes on the subscriber side with exceptions like

```
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

or

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I am quite sure this has to do with the piecewise reading in combination with
asyncio and could be solved by using `await socket.recv_multipart()`. But I am trying
to get a deeper understanding of the ZeroMQ protocol and asyncio and would
like to know why exactly it could fail.

Any ideas?

The only [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492913/asyncio-and-pyzmq-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0) that
might be related to this does not provide a good answer on why this could happen.

Edit: I came across this in the [docs](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-sendmsg), but not sure it is related:

> **Multi-part messages**
>
> A ØMQ message is composed of 1 or more message parts. Each message
> part is an independent zmq_msg_t in its own right. ØMQ ensures atomic
> delivery of messages: peers shall receive either all message parts of
> a message or none at all.