# How can I remove trailing whitespace of a utf8 string without reading through the whole string for performance?

Tags: c, performance

I have a function as follows:

```
void utf8_trim_end(char *data, int length){
  int bytecount = 1;
  int idx = length;
  char *current = data;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i += bytecount){
     if (!iswhitespace(&data[i])){
        idx = i;
     }
     bytecount = utf8_bytecount(&data[i], length-i);
  }
  data[idx] = 0;
}
```

As you can see, to make sure that we look at the start of a multibyte character we start from the beginning and iterate through. This works, but for long strings it is slow. I was wondering if there is an accepted way to start at the end and work backwards from there? (also, not looking for a library, want to do this myself)

Comment: The thing about a C string is that you need to scan it anyway to find its length. But the library `strlen` is probably quicker than you can code, so work back from there.

Comment: @WeatherVane as you can see from the function arguments, the size is already known a priori (this is often known because it allows you to speed up concatenation)

Comment: So why have you iterated from the beginning? Iterate from the end looking for non-whitespace (or the begining reached).

Comment: Because its a utf8 string which means that the characters can be multibyte. You cant just jump to the end because you dont know if you're jumping into the middle of a multibyte character.

Comment: I think the problem is that `0x20` could be the 2nd byte of a multi-byte character, so you can't just scan backwards.

Comment: @Barmar don't the continuation bytes always start with bits `10`?

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't know, I don't have UTF-8 algorithm memorized. If that's true then this isn't a problem.

Comment: [UTF-8 Continuation bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9356169/2505965)

Comment: @Barmar confirmed in an answer.

Comment: One of the design features of UTF-8 is that you can tell unambiguously whether a byte is a start byte or a continuation byte.  Some other multi-byte codesets (Shift-JIS or some of the other Japanese codesets) do not have this property; for those, you have to start at the beginning to avoid misinterpreting the data. UTF-8 is designed for easier use in that respect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* go to the end and work backwards.

All UTF-8 multibyte characters are represented as a start byte followed by a number of ‘continuation’ bytes, the number of which can be determined by examining the start byte.  All of the continuation bytes are of the form `0b10xx xxxx`.  Thus, no matter where you are in a UTF-8 string, if you're on a continuation byte, you can scan forwards *or backwards* to skip over continuation bytes and find the start byte.

Finding and identifying Unicode whitespace characters from the UTF-8 stream, reading backwards, is going to be a little fiddly, but is left as an exercise to the reader!

(The encoding is described in a good [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)).

---

(Edited to add:)

If all you (or anyone else) need is a quick-and-dirty solution, then, since codepoints in the ASCII range are encoded in UTF-8 as the corresponding bytes (ie, the space character is encoded as just `0x20`), so you could strip *most* trailing whitespace from a UTF-8-encoded string just by stripping ASCII whitespace, with ctype `isspace()`.

**But**, if it *matters* that whitespace be removed, in the sense that someone might want to hack the process, then you still have to do it ‘properly'.  That's because it's possible, though disrecommended, for characters to be encoded ‘overlong’: the space character can potentially appear as the multibyte sequences `0xC0 0xA0`, or `0xE0 0x80 0xA0`, or `0xF0 0x80 0x80 0xA0`, all of which would decode to a space character, which would thus trick a quick-and-dirty/naive whitespace stripper.

(I'll shut up now, but I've recently had to wrangle entertainingly with this stuff, so it's still fresh in my head)

Comment: As there aren't any ASCII whitespace characters in the UTF-8 sequence, it shouldn't be fiddly at all. Just look for the ASCII whitespace characters, working backwards.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not sure what you mean. There are a number of Unicode whitespace characters which are non-ASCII: [list](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:White_Space=Yes:]) (these of course include the ASCII whitespace characters)

Comment: Sorry, thinking about this more, the problem is: "given that you may be on a continuation byte, how do you identify the start of the character?" Because, as you say, there are unicode whitespace characters outside the normal ascii range

Comment: @chacham15 if your text does contain UTF-8 whitespace characters then you do need to find the first byte of a UTF-8 sequence, working backwards. It is unambiguous.

Comment: Ah, I see, the start byte will always be 0b11 according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9356203/516813 so I can scan for that.

Comment: @chacham15 the first byte will *begin* with bits `11`.

Comment: @chacham15 ...and any (single-byte) ASCII characters will match `0b0xxx xxxx`. So if you skip any b where `(b & 0xC0) == 0x80`, then you'll skip all continuation bytes.  And if you're thinking of being careful, then see [notes](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-test.txt) (the UTF-8 encoding is genuinely commendably simple, but has _way_ more edge-cases than one would guess!). Have fun...